# Exponentiating CI in Stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to run quite a few multinomial regression models. Stargazer seems like a great tool to report all results in one document for easy access. However, I noted that I get some negative confidence intervals, which does not make sense.

I tried using `apply.coef=exp` alone, where I got negative confidence intervals 
I also tried using `apply.coef=exp` and `apply.ci=exp` where the confidence interval does not make sense.

When I do `apply.ci=exp` by itself the CI are correct but it does not exponentiate the coefficient.

Health has 3 levels (poor, intermediate, ideal), poor is reference 
ETI is continuous.

```
test1 <- multinom(Health ~ ETI, data = X)
test2 <- multinom(Health ~ ETI + age + male, data = X)
test3 <- multinom(Health ~ ETI + age + male +educ +married+employed+income, data = X)
test4 <- multinom(Health ~ ETI + age + male +educ +married+depression+employed+income, data = X)
```

First code (only `apply.coef`)

```
stargazer(test1, test2, test3, test4, type="html", list(confint(test1, test2, test3, test4)),column.labels = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4"),column.separate = c(2,2,2,2), apply.coef=exp, out="X.htm")
```

The second code I tried (only `apply.ci`):

```
stargazer(test1, test2, test3, test4, type="html", apply.coef = exp  list(confint(test1, test2, test3, test4)),column.labels = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4"),column.separate = c(2,2,2,2), apply.ci=exp,apply.coef=exp, out="X.htm")
```

The last code (both `apply.ci` & `apply.coef`):

```
stargazer(test1, test2, test3, test4, type="html", apply.coef = exp  list(confint(test1, test2, test3, test4)),column.labels = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4"),column.separate = c(2,2,2,2), apply.ci=exp,apply.coef=exp, out="X.htm")
```

For the 1st code:

```
#        Ideal  Int 
#Model1 
#          (1)  (2) 
#ETI    0.453*  0.761***    
#(-0.051, 0.956)    (0.413, 1.109)
```

The exponentiated coefficients are correct but CI is wrong

For the 2nd code:

```
#           Ideal   Int 
#Model1 
#            (1)            (2) 
#ETI    -0.793***   -0.273  
#(0.273, 0.749)       (0.538, 1.078)
```

The CI is correct and matches with `cofint`

For the 3rd code:

```
#       Ideal   Int 
#      Model1   
#       (1) (2) 
#ETI    0.453*  0.761***    
#(0.950, 2.602) (1.512, 3.033)
```

The CI is wrong, I think it is doubly exponentiating

Comment: 1. negative CIs need not necessarily be wrong. 2. I'd rather use `texreg` instead of stargazer. 3. If you want to stick with stargazer, I'd try to work on the CIs on the summary(lm(x))-level instead of trying to change them using stargazer.

Answer (score 1):

If `texreg` is also ok for you, here's an example how to run `exp` on the CIs and use them for the regression table. Since you didn't include data, I used `birthwt`.

```
library(MASS)
library(nnet)
library(stargazer)
example(birthwt)

test1 <- multinom(race ~ age + lwt + bwt,
                  data = birthwt)
summary(test1)
summary(test1)["standard.errors"]

ci.low <- c(confint(test1)[1:4], confint(test1)[9:12])
ci.up <-  c(confint(test1)[5:8], confint(test1)[13:16])
texreg::screenreg(test1,
                  ci.force = T,
                  override.ci.low = exp(ci.low),
                  override.ci.up = exp(ci.up)
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use the `gtsummary` package this will allow you to easily exponentiate models in one line of code. You have to factor race to make it work.

```
library(nnet)
library(MASS)
library(gtsummary)

test1 <- multinom(factor(race) ~ age + lwt + bwt,
                  data = birthwt) %>% 
  tbl_regression( exponentiate = TRUE)


test2 <- multinom(factor(race) ~ age + lwt + bwt,
                  data = birthwt)%>% 
  tbl_regression( exponentiate = TRUE)
```